# Generic System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential system

$$ \begin{aligned} \dfrac{dx}{dt}&=5x-y \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt}&=25x-5y \end{aligned} $$

I know what form the solution will be in and my submission for the general solution to the differential equation is  $C_1\langle\frac{1}{5},1\rangle+\ C_2\left[\langle\frac{1}{5},1\rangle t+\langle 1,1\rangle\right]$ which keeps getting marked as incorrect. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your answer should satisfy $y = 5x + c$

Comment: I have $(x,y) = (x_0 + 5x_0t - y_0t, y_0 + 25x_0 t - 5y_0t)$